# can I change "delay until" granularity on cortex-m4?

Tags: embedded, ada, stm32

I'm scheduling a loop with a "delay until" clause on an STM32F4 discovery board, and when I increase the frequency, the thing stop respecting the time constraint. After some digging, I am under the impression that it's the scheduler granularity that is not up to task. One of the signs is that when I go very slow the time is mostly respected, and the faster I go, the more bonkers it go. But the tardiness seems to be discrete, like falling on the scheduling frequency limit.

here is my test code:

```
  task body PWM is
      onPeriod   : Time_Span;
      offPeriod  : Time_Span;
      period     : Time_Span;
      Next_Start : Time    := Clock;
      PWM_On     : Boolean := True;
  begin
      loop
          period    := Microseconds (1_000_000) / PWMFrequency;
          onPeriod  := period / 3;
          offPeriod := 2 * period / 3;
          if (PWM_On) then
              Off (Pattern (Next_LED));
              PWM_On     := False;
              Next_Start := Next_Start + offPeriod;
          else
              On (Pattern (Next_LED));
              PWM_On     := True;
              Next_Start := Next_Start + onPeriod;
          end if;
          delay until Next_Start;
      end loop;
 end PWM;
```

I'm not showing the oscilloscope traces, it's too complicated, suffice to say that the higher the frequency, the less the duty cycle is close to 33.3% (or even stable).

After poking around in the gnat distribution, I found that in s-bbbosu.adb:

```
--  We use the Sys_Tick timer as a periodic timer with 1 kHz rate. This
--  is a trade-off between accurate delays, limited overhead and maximum
--  time that interrupts may be disabled.

Tick_Period   : constant Timer_Interval := Clock_Frequency / 1000;
```

(and some connections to that in a function called Delay_Until in s-bbtime.adb)

Am I forced to use a native MCU timer by hand or is there some higher speed scheduling facility provided in the system?
I'm a beginner in Ada, so the answer might be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use altered system library components by placing the altered file(s) in your own code directory and rebuilding your program with `gnatmake -a` (`gprbuild` doesn’t recognise this switch on the command line, though it may be possible to include it in a GNAT Project File). Be warned, the library file recompilations are done with switches that require tight conformance to the GNAT coding style (for example, compiler warnings are treated as errors, like `-Werror` for C).

So you could say

```
Tick_Period   : constant Timer_Interval := Clock_Frequency / 10_000;
```

You’ll undoubtedly need to visit also the places where `Tick_Period` is used to determine the number of ticks to wait for a given `Duration`!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that right now. Isn't there a smarter way that would program a variable timer depending on tasks needs? (and that is already there, so I don't have to do it).

Comment: I spent 45min on it, I can't get it to compile. Problems are just snowballing out of control with softfp, crt0.o and unrecognized thumb instructions. I'll just give up this whack a mole of a build process. Thanks for your suggestion.